# VB.net/C# Datatable.Select with special characters (brackets)

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I have a vb.net Project with a Dataset with some Cells with Strings like "JB-Y[ST]Y". My Problem is you can't use datatable.select("Column like 'JB-Y[ST]Y'") because of the brackets (the select thinks this is a pattern, but I need an exact match). Anyone has an idea on this topic? I can't find a solution... Thank you!

Comment: Probably a Regex expression is required here.

Comment: In Regex you have the same problems with the brackets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution using Regex.Replace so I have a brute force solution like this

```
Public Function ReplaceBrackets(search as String) As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For Each c In search
        If c = "[" Then
            sb.Append("[[]")
        Else if c = "]" Then
            sb.Append("[]]")
        Else
            sb.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

And you can call it in your Select statement like this

```
datatable.Select("Column like '" & ReplaceBrackets(search) & "'")
```